# Update DOM during JavaScript For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I’m running up against a roadblock in Javascript that I can’t seem to overcome.

Is there any way of “updating” a view while a loop of API calls is running?

For example:

```
for (var x =0; x<array.length; x++) {
//do an api call
console.log(“Processing “+x+” of “+array.length+” records.”);
};
```

The above outputs the value of x for each loop to the console.  However, this:

```
for (var x =0; x<array.length; x++) {
var body = document.getElementById(“view_100”);
//do an api call
body.innerHTML = “Processing “+x+” of “+array.length+” records.”;
};
```

Does not update the dom until after all of the loops have finished and then shows only the last value of x.

Any thoughts on how I can keep a user informed as to what is going on during a long javascript loop?

Comment: Typo here? `body.innterHTML = “Processing “+x+” of “+array.length+” records.”;` I would expect innerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

for (var x = 0; x<array.length; x++) {
var body = document.getElementById("view_100");
//do an api call
//append the text instead of reassigning
body.innerHTML += "Processing "+(x+1)+" of "+array.length+" records.";

/* cleaner way
var message = document.createElement("p");
message.innerText = "Processing "+(x+1)+" of "+array.length+" records."
body.append(message)
*/
};
```

```html
<div id="view_100"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use append element

```
const body = document.getElementById(“view_100”);
for (var x =0; x<array.length; x++) {
    const statusEl = document.createElement('div');
    statusEl.innerHTML = `Processing ${x + 1} of ${array.length} records`
    //do an api call
    body.appendChild(statusEl);
};
```